# If $y_n>0$, $\lim{\frac{x_n}{y_n}=a}$ and $\sum{y_n}=+\infty$, then $\lim{\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{y_1+y_2+...+y_n}=a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having trouble to show:

If $y_n>0$, $\lim{\frac{x_n}{y_n}=a}$ and $\sum{y_n}=+\infty$, then $\lim{\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{y_1+y_2+...+y_n}=a}$

I'm trying to use the fact that $\lim{\frac{x_n}{y_n}=a}$ $\implies$ $a-\epsilon\le\frac{x_n}{y_n}\le a+\epsilon$ and then work from here, but did not seems to work (or maybe I'm just doing it in the wrong way?).

I tried work from the limit that I need to prove too, and show that is less than $\epsilon$, separating the sum in 2 parts with large and small n's to use the limit from hypotesis, but nothing.

So, I honestly don't know, If I did something wrong, or if I'm ignoring some theorem that should help me here.

Any help and hints are welcome.

Comment: Everything you say you tried or are trying, that didn't work, you merely claim so.  How can we answer "If I did something wrong" ... without seeing your actual attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a good idea. Indeed, since $\frac{x_n}{y_n} \to a$, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N$ such that for $k \ge N$ you get $(a-\varepsilon)y_k \le x_k \le (a+\varepsilon)y_k$ (we've used that $y_k > 0$ here, so that the signs of inequalities remain). Then for $n \ge N$ you can rewrite $$ \frac{x_1+ ... + x_n}{y_1 + ... + y_n} = \frac{x_1 + ... + x_N}{y_1 + ... + y_n} + \frac{x_{N+1} + ... x_N}{y_1 + ... + y_n} \le \frac{x_1+ ... +x_N}{y_1 + ... y_n} + (a+\varepsilon)\frac{y_{N+1} + ... + y_n}{y_1+...+y_n} $$
Now, with $N$ fixed, you have $\frac{x_1+...+x_N}{y_1+...+y_n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, due to divergence of series $\sum_k y_k$. Moreover, $$ \frac{y_{N+1} + ... y_n}{y_1+...+y_n} = 1 - \frac{y_1 +... +y_N}{y_1 +... +y_n} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 1 - 0 = 1$$ due to the same reason. Hence $\limsup_n \frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{y_1 + ... +y_n} \le a+\varepsilon$. Similarly you can prove that $\liminf_n \frac{x_1 + ... x_n}{y_1 + ... + y_n} \ge a-\varepsilon$ and since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary you can conclude $$ a \le \liminf_n \frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{y_1 + ... +y_n} \le \limsup_n \frac{x_1 + ... + x_n}{y_1 + ... + y_n} \le a $$ and so the limit exists and is equal to $a$.